Accessing Intel Software RAID (vROC) on KVM Guest (Debian) from Red Hat Host
I have Intel Software RAID (Intel® VROC) configured on my Red Hat host machine, and I would like to access its status etc  within a Debian-based KVM guest VM.
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --detail-platform
mdadm: imsm capabilities not found for controller: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0 (type SATA)
mdadm: imsm capabilities not found for controller: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (type SATA)
      Platform : Intel(R) Virtual RAID on CPU
       Version : 8.5.0.1096
   RAID Levels : raid0 raid1 raid10
   Chunk Sizes : 4k 8k 16k 32k 64k 128k
   2TB volumes : supported
     2TB disks : supported
     Max Disks : 96
   Max Volumes : 2 per array, 24 per controller
3rd party NVMe : supported
I/O Controller : /sys/devices/pci0000:9a/0000:9a:00.5 (VMD)
NVMe under VMD : /dev/nvme0n1 (S64FNN0X507593)
                 Encryption(Ability|Status): SED|Unencrypted
NVMe under VMD : /dev/nvme2n1 (S64FNN0X507591)
                 Encryption(Ability|Status): SED|Unencrypted
NVMe under VMD : /dev/nvme1n1 (S64FNN0X507583)
                 Encryption(Ability|Status): SED|Unencrypted
I/O Controller : /sys/devices/pci0000:c6/0000:c6:00.5 (VMD)


[root@localhost ~]# sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
         Container : /dev/md/imsm, member 0
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 890806272 (849.54 GiB 912.19 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 890806272 (849.54 GiB 912.19 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2

             State : active
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync


              UUID : 991e034f:faaee5eb:fc8c7c50:8482898a
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       1     259        0        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1
       0     259        2        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1

While I understand I can use PCI passthrough to directly expose the RAID controller to the guest, I am concerned about losing access to the RAID from the host.
One approach I’ve considered is using file sharing to dump all the required RAID data into a shared file, which can then be mounted by the VM. However, this method doesn’t feel flexible enough for my needs since, after rebooting the VM, I would need to manually remount the file. I also prefer not to add mount entries in the VM’s /etc/fstab.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Have a monitoring system record the status of the host array, and make that data accessible to the guest.
Several existing monitoring scripts know how to check Linux md arrays. mdadm commands or /proc/mdstat.  At least a couple essential metrics, like state or if the array is redundant.
If instead you need some custom mdadm commands, script that.  Allow a specific user group to ssh in and run it, from the guest to the host.  This breaks the usual isolation desired between guests and hosts for security reasons. But running the commands on the host is better than letting the guest control the host's disks.

I have achieved the above as mentioned here
https://serverfault.com/a/1169282/1155087
Could you please help me understand the possible RAID failure statuses with mdadm on Intel Software RAID?
I have posted the query here, and I really appreciate your assistance on this.
https://serverfault.com/questions/1169212/what-are-the-possible-raid-failure-statuses-with-mdadm-on-intel-software-raid

I recently acquired the Virtiofs tool to enable file sharing between the RHEL host and KVM guest.
https://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html

https^://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html
Steps to Share Files Between KVM Host and Debian Guest Using Virtiofs

Enable XML Editing in Virt-Manager
Edit Virtual Machine Settings
Enable Shared Memory
Add a Filesystem Device
Configure the Shared Folder

Source Path: Shared folder on the host machine.
Target Path: Desired folder name for the shared folder on the guest.


Start the VM
Install virtiofs package on the guest VM
sudo apt-get install virtiofsd (Debian)


Create a mount point for the shared folder
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/shared

Example: /mnt/shared
Mount the shared folder using virtiofs
sudo mount -t virtiofs host_shared /mnt/shared



